# check for null when destructuring data with useSelector

Tags: javascript

How can I check for null when destructuring my data:

```
   const {
      vehicles: {
         data: { reminderVehicles },
      },
   } = useSelector((state) => state);
```

The below code gives me

> null is not an object, evaluating vehicles.data.reminderVehicles

```
   document.getElementById("VehicleRegistration").value = "${
        (prepopVehicleReg && reminderVehicles[0]?.Registration) || ""
     }";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always assign a default value to it.

```js
const myData = {
  one: 1,
  two: 2,
  nested: {
    three: 1
  }
};

const {one = null} = myData;
const {five = null} = myData;
const {nested: {three}} = myData;
const {nested: {six = 'Default'}} = myData;


console.log({
 one, 
 three,
 five, 
 six
});
```

In your case, it should be (assuming `reminderVehicles`  is an array)

```js
const {
    vehicles: {
        data: {
            reminderVehicles
        } = {
            reminderVehicles: []
        }
    } = {}
} = useSelector((state) => state);
```

But this is not readable and looks very complicated